# Carrierwave juste delete file but doesn't clear database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use `carrierewave` to add user avatar in my app

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

so, when i try to remove avatar with `remove_avatar` method it just remove the file but not clear database column's value

i have found a discussion about the same subject here : [CarrierWave only deletes files, doesn't clear the column or clear the uploader](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/401) but it seem an old discussion (2 years ago) and maybe carrierewave is updated to fix this issue. any idea please ?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the following?

```
user.remove_avatar = true
user.save
```

Comment: yes already find this and tried it and now is working, but not sure if this is the best way ! also you forget bang for save method, like this : user.save! :D

Comment: The alternative is to run `user.remove_avatar!` and `user.update_column(:avatar, nil)`, but I personally think that's sketchier than the above.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to the [Taavo comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19010951/2757230):

Note, that when you call .save(!), you save ALL current changes in the record. 
So, if you edit record, then want to remove avatar (i.e. via AJAX request) but DON'T want to save other changes - you should find another way. Try `user.update_attribute(:avatar, nil)` instead `user.save`